# Angular 8 Upgrade - ng build command gives @angular/platform-browser errors

Tags: angular

I'm currently in the process of upgrading an Angular 7 app to Angular 8 and I'm running into some issues - I've previously upgraded from Angular 5 and 6 relatively smoothly so I have some experience with the process using [Angular's upgrade guide](https://update.angular.io).

I've followed all of the steps and have successfully upgraded all of my Angular dependencies to `8.1.x`. I'm now using the `{ static: false }` with ViewChild and my imports for Angular Material are up to date using deeper imports.

The issue arises when I attempt to build my application using `ng build --aot --prod --build-optimizer=false`. With this I get the following error.

```
chunk {0} runtime.e9d4a8365190f9ee7214.js (runtime) 2.21 kB [entry] [rendered]
chunk {1} main.82103d8cb2976079a759.js (main) 6.52 MB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {2} pdfjsWorker.4df5ce1f8ece90d58a9f.js (pdfjsWorker) 741 kB  [rendered]
chunk {3} polyfills.884b7d233bf412d2ec81.js (polyfills) 63.7 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {4} polyfills-es5.fb30af840b34e7fa0bb5.js (polyfills-es5) 69.8 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {5} styles.169e0b9ec596a5a72c8f.css (styles) 66.5 kB [initial] [rendered]
Date: 2019-07-26T00:55:16.623Z - Hash: 142d65823e318484d40b - Time: 68210ms

ERROR in ./src/app/app.module.ngfactory.js 318:10580-10593
"export 'DOCUMENT' (imported as 'i129') was not found in '@angular/platform-browser'
ERROR in ./node_modules/ng-intercom/fesm5/ng-intercom.js 501:83-91
"export 'DOCUMENT' was not found in '@angular/platform-browser'
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! my-app@0.39.3290 build: `npx ng build --aot --prod --build-optimizer=false && npx tsc -p tsconfig.json`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the my-app@0.39.3290 build script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
```

I'm not really sure what's going on here with the whole `export DOCUMENT` issue.

Here's what I get when I run `ng --version`.

```
Angular CLI: 8.1.2
Node: 10.15.3
OS: darwin x64
Angular: 8.1.2
... animations, cli, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... language-service, platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic
... router

Package                            Version
------------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect          0.801.2
@angular-devkit/build-angular      0.801.2
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer    0.801.2
@angular-devkit/build-webpack      0.801.2
@angular-devkit/core               8.1.2
@angular-devkit/schematics         8.1.2
@angular/cdk                       8.1.1
@angular/http                      7.2.15
@angular/material                  8.1.1
@angular/material-moment-adapter   8.1.1
@ngtools/webpack                   8.1.2
@schematics/angular                8.1.2
@schematics/update                 0.801.2
rxjs                               6.5.2
typescript                         3.4.5
webpack                            4.35.2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the dependency ng-intercom is importing DOCUMENT from platform-browser, whereas it should now be imported from '@angular/common'.

Try seeing if there is a new version of ng-intercom  that supports a more recent version of Angular, then try running ng update again.

Comment: Updating ng-intercom to the latest version solved it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Document is no longer in `@angular/platform-browser`
It is located in `@angular/common`

```
import { DOCUMENT } from '@angular/common'<----replace;
```

> Reference https://angular.io/api/common/DOCUMENT

Comment: I came across this change earlier when I was looking for solutions but the issue is I don't have that import anywhere in my app.